# Why can nil be returned from a non-optional function in this case?

Tags: swift, null, swift2

I am trying the below code in Playground and I don't quite understand why the compiler doesn't give an error when `bar`, which is `nil`, is returned from a non-optional function; and why it does when essentially `nil` is being compared to `nil` and gives an error message which seems not correct when claiming that `foobar` can never be `nil`.

EDIT:
Since `Optional` is also `Any`, why returning `nil` directly as in `foo2` is not allowed?

```
func foo() -> Any {
    let bar: String? = nil
    return bar
}

let foobar = foo()

if foobar == nil {

}

func foo2() -> Any {
    return nil
}
```

[image]

Comment: Optional is Any, but Any isn't Comparable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How about the error message which claims that `foobar` can never be `nil` when actually it is?

Comment: You can save `nil` into `Any` but `Any` itself is not an optional so you cannot compare with `nil`. Frankly, don't use `Any` at all. You can't do anything with `Any`. When you get `Any`, cast it first to a specific type, e.g. `String`.

Comment: "Frankly, don't use Any at all." Absolutely great advice. Every so often, I've seen a bizarre corner case where an `Any` parameter might make sense (things like `print` that really, really mean "I can take anything") but I can't think of any case where it's a reasonable return type. What do you expect your caller to do with it?

Comment: @Sulthan Apparently we cannot save `nil` into `Any` because `let _: Any = nil` just won't work.

Comment: @ThanhPham That's because `Any` isn't [`NilLiteralConvertible`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/NilLiteralConvertible/), but an Optional is. I'd also like to agree with all the points above – don't fight the type system. If your function returns a `String?`, then annotate it as such – there is very rarely an actual use case for using `Any`.

Comment: @ThanhPham `nil` is a literal that gets converted into `Optional<T>.None`. `nil` without a type means nothing. You can store anything into `Any`, including `Optional<T>.None` but you have to give it a type. In this case it's impossible to infer the type from context so you would have to use directly `Optional<String>.None` or `nil as String?`.

Comment: Thanks @originaluser2. Your answer is exactly the kind of answer I expected!

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan for pointing out that literal without a type means nothing. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's explain exactly what happens in your code:

```
func foo() -> Any {
    let bar: String? = nil
    return bar
}
```

`nil` is a literal that gets converted to type `String?` (or `Optional<String>`), that is, into `Optional<String>.None`.

Then it is cast to `Any`. Anything can be cast to `Any`, including optionals. Basically you have decided to hide the underlining types.

Then `foobar == nil`. Note that `==` is an operation that is not automatically available for all types. The comparison with `nil` is defined on optional types, e.g. for `Optional<T>` with another `Optional<T>`.

In this case you have `Any` and a `nil` literal. `Any` itself is not an optional, therefore you cannot compare it directly with `nil`.

You can cast it to an optional `Any`.

```
let optionalFoobar = any as Any?
```

However, now the variable contains a double optional `Optional<Any>.Some(Optional<String>.None)` and comparison with `nil` won't work.

The only thing that would work would be:

```
if (foobar as Any?) as? String == nil {
    print("is nil")
}
```

In short, don't use `Any` and if you are using non-optional `Any`, don't store optional types into it, it will get really complicated and unusable in practice.

Answer (score 5):

> EDIT: Since Optional is also Any, why returning nil directly as in foo2 is not allowed?

Because `nil` has no type of its own. It says there's nothing, but nothing of *what*? You have to pick that type:

```
func foo2() -> Any {
    return nil as String?
}
```

Even this is legal:

```
func foo2() -> Any {
    return nil as Any?
}
```

But never, never do this. `Any` is not a normal tool. It's a last-ditch escape-hatch for the type system to deal with very special problems (like `print`). When you mix the magic of `Any` with the magic of `Optional` (specifically Optional-promotion), you will tend to constantly run into confusing errors and find yourself running the wrong overloads.

`AnyObject` does come up a bit, but only because of bridges to ObjC, which uses untyped values a lot (though this is improving and `AnyObject` is becoming less common). But it still rarely makes sense to return an `AnyObject` in Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

`Any` is not Optional so you cannot compare to nil. If you want to compare to nil, you return type must be an Optional type: `Any?` for example:

```
func foo() -> Any? {
    let bar: String? = nil
    return bar
}

let foobar = foo()

if foobar == nil {
    print("foobar is nil")
}
```